# Porque Microsoft Edge me devuelve una pagina en blanco XML-XSL

Tags: xml, microsoft, xsl, xslt, edge

Estoy usando XML Copy Editor para trabajar con XML y XSL pero al momento de abrir con el navegador me arroja una pagina en blanco.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y, al hacerlo con otro navegador (Firefox) me sale solo el contenido sin mostrar los estilos que he puesto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

libreria5.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Ejercicio Librería</title>
        <style>
         body {text-align:center;}
          span {font-weight: bold;}
          .azul{background-color: cyan;}
          table{margin:auto;
          text-align:left;}
          .color{back-ground-color:salmon;}
        </style>
      </head>
      
      <body>
      <h1>Librería</h1>
      <table border="1">
        <tr class="azul">
          <th>ISBN</th>
          <th>Título</th>
          <th>Autor</th>
          <th>Precio</th>
        </tr>
        
        <xsl:for-each select="/libreria/libro">
          <xsl:if test="/titulo[starts-with(text(), 'P']">
              <tr>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="isbn"/></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="titulo"/></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="autor"/></td>
                  <td class="color"><xsl:value-of select="precio"/></td>
                </tr>
        </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: lo has configurado el navegador para que lo accepte?

Comment: @JavierG.Raya como lo configuro?

Comment: Avísame si te funciona.

Comment: Lo he probado en varios navegadores y no me ha funcionado en ninguno.

Comment: entonces es tu codigo

Comment: El código lo he probado en otros ordenadores y me funcionaba sin problemas, es la configuración de mi ordenador(algo debo de estar haciendo mal). Me podrías decir otros programas parecidos a XML Editor que pueda usar, por favor. Gracias.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136365/discussion-between-javier-g-raya-and-rosa).

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes ***google chrome*** puedes realizarlo para ***Windows*** debes de ir a propiedades de google.

Pincha con el botón derecho en el **Chrome/Propiedades** añadir comillas doble a la ruta de esta manera `"turutadegoogle"` y le añades al final esto `--allow-file-access-from-files`

**Quedaria algo asi en mi caso.**

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files`

Donde esta ***el cuadrado azul***, pues lo añades al final y solucionado, deberás reiniciar el equipo y abrirlo desde el escritorio o donde tengas el icono si no deseas ponerlo modificando las ***propiedades de google***, puedes abrir un ***terminal con permisos de administrador*** y poner `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files.`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Nota Importante :*** Esta configuración lo he probado con ***Google Chrome, Opera y Opera GX*** siguiendo el mismo paso, con ***Firefox*** no se si funciona pero creo que si.